# Git file write error (No space left in device)

Tags: git

I'm encountering this Git error while trying to push a local branch. I tried possible ways and followed a few SO posts, but they didn't help.

> remote: error: file write error (No space left on device) remote:
> fatal: unable to write sha1 file error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit

Comment: @kusma This does not help! I need a solution.

Comment: why there is a downvote ?

Comment: @kusma Before posting it in SO, I obviously knew (from the error log) there is out of disk-space in remote end, and what I was expecting the steps to free up from remote disk space. Can anyone free up some space if he/she is not in group admin? I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: An administrator on the remote end needs to free up space.

Comment: could this happen if the local machine runs out of memory? I get this error when doing a `git commit blah blah blah` .

Answer (score 7):

TLDR:  run the command:

`git gc`

That worked for me despite the error seeming like it resides on the server.

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote, but this command worked for me.  I was not out of disk space but was still getting the error.  Running this command solved my issue.

Comment: Ironically, I'm getting this error while running git gc!

Comment: This command fixed my problem as well. `git gc` simply clean up unnecessary files and optimize the local repository.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no space left in your remote, check this other post:

[Hudson: returned status code 141: fatal: write error: No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681774/hudson-returned-status-code-141-fatal-write-error-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: Thanks @jpina.I cleaned /tmp files and ran a git gc, however still no success.

Comment: same with me, ran `$ git gc` but the error prompt me.

Answer (score 3):

You're out of drive space. Delete some unused files from anywhere on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

I got the error having enough space left on device when I tried to `git add` large files (>1GB). Adding these files to `.gitignore` solved it. See also this post:

[Max file size and max repository size in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230721/max-file-size-and-max-repository-size-in-git)

Comment: I'm having the same issue. BTW the link you gave is referencing this question

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a remote server, try deleting the files inside /tmp.

```
cd /tmp
rm -rf *
```